# Using %pwd in markdown (jupyter notebook) to import images from directory

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am writing in a markdown cell on Jupyter Notebook. I am using the following code to look in the directory that the current notebook is being loaded from and show the image "img.png". This code works. I just wanted to know if there was a way to make the "%pwd" 'invisible' upon running the cell, as it obviously is not meant to be showing in the passage I am writing.

```
%pwd
<img src="img.png" alt="Electrical network" width=1000>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your html doesn't work just fine even if you simply remove the `%pwd`? That should just display your working directory, not change it. http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pwd

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `%pwd`

You can simply use `<img src="img.png" alt="Python" style="width: 400px;"/>` to load images